# SPF=neutral, email from Google Apps domain

Tags: email, google-apps, spf

I'd like to allow Google Apps and CampaignMonitor (email marketing service) to send emails from my domain.

I've set my TXT records to:

> v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com include:cmail1.com ~all

However, all emails sent from Google Apps shows:

> Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 209.85.216.43 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of example@example.com) client-ip=209.85.216.43;
>   Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 209.85.216.43 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of example@example.com) smtp.mail=example@example.com; dkim=pass header.i=@example.com

How can I make my emails SPF "pass" instead of "neutral"?

Comment: this is Ros from Campaign Monitor. You're more than welcome to get in touch with our team with details, as we regularly help out with email authentication issues: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/contact All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening for all emails? Because doesn't make sense if you are sending from Gmail and you have the _spf.google.com in your SPF it should pass.